# Get Number From Edit text, won't add up?

Tags: java, android

I am not able to get sum of the two numbers entered in a pair of EditText fields. The EditTexts are set to take numeric input.

#### Java    :

```
EditText x1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Tensione);
EditText x2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Potenza);
String x3;
x3 = x1 + x2;
```

#### activity.xml:

```
EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/Tensione"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Testo_Calcolo1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:editable="false"
    android:numeric="integer|signed|decimal" /

EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberPassword|number|numberDecimal|numberSigned"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/Potenza"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView8Testo_Calcolo"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:numeric="integer|signed|decimal" />
```

#### Error:

> Error:(51, 21) operator + cannot be applied to android.widget.EditText,android.widget.EditText

Answer (score 4):

Your issue is that an EditText is not a number or even a String. It is a View that has a String contained in it.

```
EditText x1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Tensione);
EditText x2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Potenza);
...

// get the Strings from the EditTexts
String x1Contents = x1.getText().toString();
String x2Contents = x2.getText().toString();

// convert Strings to ints
int x1Number = Integer.parseInt(x1Contents);
int x2Number = Integer.parseInt(x2Contents);

// then add them together
int x3Number = x1Number + x2Number;
```

This is not a complete solution. You will still need to grab the contents when you know the EditTexts have values and make sure that it is numeric input or ensure you handle non-numeric input appropriately.

Comment: @GiovanniD'ippolito But you should now get a very different error. For that new problem you should ask a new question as multiple questions in one or completely rewriting a question with shifting goals is not allowed on Stack Overflow. I will keep an eye out for the new question and continue to help you there.

Comment: That is the correct answer, you should learn a bit more about the android basics ! And btw, if this code is not in a listener callback (like a btn click or textchange) this sum is only gonna happen [probably] once (if it's onCreate for example).

Comment: @LeonardoFerrari, hence the `...` and final paragraph. =0p A full answer like that would be a bit outside the scope of the Question and judging by the level of the Question, lead to further Questions or clarifications. Also, knowing nothing about the app in development possibly lead the OP down a path not suited to their app.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, it was just for clarification for newcommers on android. Digging a little here and on google doesn't hurt, right ?!

Comment: @LeonardoFerrari, Nope, not at all; it's a good suggestion. Just clearing up why I wouldn't go that in-depth here and how I addressed it in the answer.

Comment: Sure, I share the same opinion with you @indivisible :)